# JRE 7 issue : Java Plug-in directory is not visible

Tags: java, installshield-le

I have installed jre 7 and in the installshield wizard REG_JAVA_IE_PLUGIN_ROOT variable is not picking the location of java plugin.The value for REG_JAVA_IE_PLUGIN_ROOT=SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in\ in the registry file . How to resolve the issue please help ? thanks for your time

Comment: Have you installed the correct version according to your machine. Is your machine 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I have installed 64 bit jre7 and my system is also 64 bit